# CMake: add files as content to Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, windows-store

CMake since version 3.1 can create Windows Store/Windows Phone 8.1 projects.

Is it possible to add resource file (say, png image) to resulting Visual Studio 2013 project (Modern UI app) and **mark it as content** to force copying it to output directory when building from VS? If yes, how this can be achieved?

For example configure_file just adds file to the project directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a flag for that called VS_DEPLOYMENT_CONTENT in cmake
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_sf/VS_DEPLOYMENT_CONTENT.html

By the way, Microsoft has a cmake fork with more update support for windows universal app that isn't a part of the cmake main repository yet.
https://github.com/Microsoft/CMake/
You might find it useful.

Comment: There is also usage sample in the repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/CMake/blob/feature/Win10/Tests/VSWinStorePhone/CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

To copy files, say PNG images as you wanted, to the output directory, you can do like this:

```
file(GLOB files_needed_to_copy
    your-data-directory/*.png
)
file(COPY ${files_needed_to_copy} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

This will make the copy operation happen while cmake-ing.

Comment: This copies files to ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} however they are not included in project. Visual Studio shows "Included In Project" as "False" for these files.